# Why can't $uus$ and $uds$ quark content have $I = 1$ Isospin?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, isospin-symmetry, baryons

Well, I know the isospin singlet with $I=0$ and isospin triplet with $I = 1$. But for $I = 0$, why it must be $uds$ quark content rather than other  assembly like $uus$ or $dds$? $ud$ can have $I = 0$ and $I = 1$, but $uu$ and $dd$ can only have $I = 1$, so why?

Comment: related , and answer therein  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255520/

Comment: What’s the question? It appears to be why don’t sigma baryons exist.

Comment: Reassure the reader you understand the isospin of the Λ, Σ ⁰, and Σ*⁰, and the +  and - isopartners of the latter.

Comment: "because u is the I_z = +1/2, and d is the I_z = -1/2, so uu must have I_z = +1, which is incompatible with total I = 0"

Answer (score 3):

> can have =0 and =1, but  and  can only have =1, so why?

I am not quite sure what you are really asking, or where your logical snag lies. The obvious answer is interchange symmetry.

Ignoring the *s*, which is an isosinglet, the antisymmetric combination of two different light quarks, ${ud-du \over \sqrt{2}}$, cannot have its isospin raised, so it is an isosinglet.

But the symmetric combination, ${ud+du \over \sqrt{2}}$,  can have it raised to *uu* or lowered to *dd*, so it is part of an isotriplet. We assign the former to the Λ baryon, and the latter to the Σ⁰.

Note the respective isosymmetry in the full octet baryon strange wavefunctions,
$$
|\Lambda \uparrow\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}} \Bigl ( 
|( u\downarrow d\uparrow -d\downarrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow u\downarrow -u\uparrow d\downarrow ) ~ s\uparrow\rangle \\ +
|  u\downarrow s\uparrow  d\uparrow -d\downarrow s\uparrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow s\uparrow  u\downarrow -u\uparrow s\uparrow  d\downarrow \rangle \\ +
|s\uparrow ( u\downarrow d\uparrow -d\downarrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow u\downarrow -u\uparrow d\downarrow)\rangle \Bigr ),\\
|\Sigma^0 \uparrow\rangle = \frac{1}{6} \Bigl ( 2|( u\uparrow d\uparrow 
+d\uparrow u\uparrow)~ s\downarrow\rangle  
+2|s\downarrow ( u\uparrow d\uparrow 
+d\uparrow u\uparrow) \rangle \\ 
-|( u\downarrow d\uparrow +d\downarrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow u\downarrow +u\uparrow d\downarrow ) ~ s\uparrow\rangle -|s\uparrow ( u\downarrow d\uparrow +d\downarrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow u\downarrow +u\uparrow d\downarrow )  \rangle \\ +2
|  u\uparrow s\downarrow  d\uparrow +d\uparrow s\downarrow u\uparrow  \rangle   -
|  u\downarrow s\uparrow  d\uparrow +d\downarrow s\uparrow u\uparrow +d\uparrow s\uparrow  u\downarrow +u\uparrow s\uparrow  d\downarrow \rangle 
   \Bigr ).
$$

These wavefunctions have mixed flavor and spin symmetries, but an iso-cum-spin interchange is *always symmetric* (as in synchronized swimming!), so that, given the inevitable color antisymmetrizantion (suppressed here), all quarks are antisymmetrized w.r.t. *any* interchange, as fermions should always  be.

You can now appreciate how, in contrast to the above, in the baryon decuplet (spin 3/2) hence always spin symmetric, there can [be no isosinglet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259346/why-is-there-no-baryon-isospin-singlet-with-spin-3-2/259358#259358): no  Λ* !! Quarks being fermions prevent that.